# How to find Port number of IP address?

Tags: url, dns, ip-address, port

We can find out `IP` address of a `domain name` or `URL`. But how to find out `Port` number on which a domain name is hosted?

Comment: Did you mean to say "IP address of a domain name or URL", and "port number on which a domain name is hosted"?  Otherwise, the question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Unfortunately the standard DNS A-record (domain name to IP address)
>   used by web-browsers to locate web-servers does not include a port
>   number. Web-browsers use the URL protocol prefix (http://) to
>   determine the port number (http = 80, https = 443, ftp = 21, etc.)
>   unless the port number is specifically typed in the URL (for example
>   "http://www.simpledns.com:5000" = port 5000).

[Can I specify a TCP/IP port number for my web-server in DNS? (Other than the standard port 80)](http://www.simpledns.com/kb.aspx?kbid=1042)

Answer (score 19):

Quite an old question, but might be helpful to somebody in need.

If you know the url,

1. open the chrome browser,
2. open developer tools in chrome ,
3. Put the url in search bar and hit enter
4. look in **network** tab, you will see the ip and port both

Comment: Afterwards, I had to add remote address field to the table

Comment: Just a precisation. At point 4, inside the programmer tools box, you must look for your IP under the "name" column on the left, and then for the variable "remote address" under "General" paragraph, under "headers" tab, in the column on the right.

Comment: @Tms91 I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: I still don't find it. I am in Network tab but there is no programmer toolbox. Can you attach a screenshot please?

Answer (score 9):

DNS server usually have a standard of [ports used](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197515%28WS.10%29.aspx). But if it's different, you could try [nmap](http://nmap.org/) and do a port scan like so:

```
> nmap 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

The port is usually fixed, for DNS it's 53.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a normal
then the port number is always 80
and may be written as http://www.somewhere.com:80
Though you don't need to specify it as :80 is the default of every web browser.

If the site chose to use something else then they are intending to hide from anything not sent by a "friendly" or linked to.
Those ones usually show with https
and their port number is unknown and decided by their admin.

If you choose to runn a port scanner trying every number nn from say 10000 to 30000 in https://something.somewhere.com:nn
Then your isp or their antivirus will probably notice and disconnect you.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the `netstat -a` command will give you a list of connections to your system/server where you are executing the command.

For example it will display as below, where 35070 is the port number

```
 TCP    10.144.0.159:**52121**    sd-s-fgh:35070   ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

Port numbers are defined by convention.  HTTP servers generally listen on port 80, ssh servers listen on 22.  But there are no requirements that they do.

Answer (score 0):

```
 domain = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('web.base.url')
```

I got the hostname and port number using this.