# iOS: how to get the http connection's source port

Tags: ios, http, port

I use NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection to access server:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PROPFIND"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
...
NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[coon start];
```

I know we need a `destination IP` and `destination port` to connect server;

the question is:
how to get&set the `source port` of my http connection? (just mean I need the local port of my HTTP connection); server need it for NAT settings. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614318/how-to-find-port-number-of-ip-address apparently, unless the port number is specified in the URL, it is determined by the prefix such as "http" (port 80), "https" (port 443), "ftp" etc.

Comment: I read it but seems no help. I mean the I need the source port Not the server's port. I don't know it exactly about HTTP&&TCP/IP&&Socket. I just know I can bind a source port for socket, but can not find a way set local port for http. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I had to do some work to create my own custom HTTP, and then support for setting the sour port of the socket the HTTP used.

Comment: Can you give more details on how you did this? Others are also asking similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31060498/4577867