# How to specify the source port for an http request in iOS

Tags: ios, http, port

I know that it's an unusual thing to need to do, but I need to specify the SOURCE port to be used in an outgoing http(s) request in iOS. I know that there are many different 'standard' ways to send http(s) requests -- from what I understand the most usual involve NSURLConnection and NSURLSession, but I couldn't see if I can specify the source port. Is it possible to somehow use a socket interface to create the socket and then use **this** socket with NSURLConnection or NSURLSession?

Or perhaps (as a hack) can one specify the ephemeral port range that my app can use (so I'll restrict it to a range of 5 or 10 ports)?

As a last grasping at straws: is there some ip masquerading or other rules that are available on the iOS device that the app could use to ensure that the source port is correct? (I suppose one could write a process which just does masquerading by hand to the correct fixed port -- essentially write a local http forwarding proxy -- is that my only possibility?)

I don't need any fancy feature or control of these http(s) requests **except** that they need to come from a certain very narrow range of port numbers.

thanks very much.

If you want to ask why I have such a stupid requirement, please feel free to ask privately -- but don't clutter up this question. THanks!!

I note that just a year ago, [iOS: how to get the http connection's source port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307216/ios-how-to-get-the-http-connections-source-port) was asked, but that asked about READING the ephemeral port chosen by the system.

thanks

Comment: Short answer, no. Unless you write your own socket layer. What is the use-case in specifying an outbound port number in http request? What would you do if the port is already taken?

Comment: The use-case is that there are some middleboxes  at the two end-networks (i.e. near the clients and near the servers). I need a way to reliably mark certain requests  for different treatment by them. Can't use TOS bits - they get zeroed out as they hit the public Internet.  To mitigate against the port being already taken, I actually declare a block of 100 source ports as "special". in the **highly** unlikely case that all 100 ports are taken, the user gets an error. Finally, it's easy to verify if a request with one of my source ports is really mine, so i'm not worried about rogue requests

Comment: An Apple TN states "If you're using NSURLConnection, 
it is implemented using a CFStream (a CFHTTPStream) which in 
turn uses another CFStream (a CFSocketStream this time) which 
manages the underlying socket." Is it possible to use NSURLConnection 
(or NSURLSession) and get access to the underlying 
CFSocketStream -- just enough to bind the underlying socket to 
some specific local port number? This would indeed be writing 
my own socket layer -- but all other 
functionality would be untouched. (I know I'm oversimplifying, in 
real life I'd need to handle multiple sockets per session)

Comment: Did you find a work around you are willing to share?

Comment: Yes, although hardly generic in nature. All requests were https, and in fact  both client and  server presented a cert  during the SSL establishment. These clients used a cert with a special CNAME, and the middleboxes had enough power and state to identify packets which belongs to SLL streams which had a Cert  with that name.  Hideous, I realize.