# How to handle jenkins http -> https redirect?

Tags: jenkins, jetty

I currently have jenkins set up with AWS fargate with ECS. There is a classic load balancer in front.

Things i have tried:

- Putting nginx onto the core jenkins image and issuing a re-direct but I do not use nginx for anything else so I am against this solution.
- I have switched to an application load balancer but this does not work as I use the fargate plugin for my jenkins job with their own agents. The agents traffic is on tcp 5050. Perhaps I am doing something wrong here?

I have looked into using Jetty to issue the redirect.
I noticed winstone supports [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/winstone/pull/98) and it has been included in Jenkins 2.243

- Winstone 5.10: Add --httpsRedirectHttp option that activates automatic HTTP request redirects to HTTPs. [(pull 4811)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/4811)

I have already defined some options in my core jenkins container

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2048m ${JAVA_OPTS:-}"
```

How would I extend this to include the http -> https functionallity included in jenkins 2.243?

Comment: Is your jenkins up and running? Are you saying `http://yourjenkins.com` is already in full working condition and now trying to make it work with `https://yourjenkins.com` ?

Comment: yes, jenkins is up and running. ```https://yourjenkins.com``` works. I am trying to create an automatic re-direct when a user hits ```http://yourjenkins.com``` to ```https://yourjenkins.com```. At the moment ```http://yourjenkins.com``` just times out.

Comment: I would not try to add a new tool `Winstone` to the mix yet. Can you try to open the HTTP port instead? Ref:

Comment: Are you able to `ping http://yourjenkins.com` 
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614318/how-to-find-port-number-of-ip-address and https://serverfault.com/questions/89399/https-timeout-while-http-works

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/jenkinsci/winstone/pull/98, I added --httpsRedirectHttp. It works!

-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=80 --httpsPort=443 --httpsRedirectHttp --httpsKeyStore="%LocalAppData%\Jenkins\my.jks" --httpsKeyStorePassword= --webroot="%LocalAppData%\Jenkins\war"